# Play sound on Sprite Image on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, phaser-framework

I created a sprite with 10 images in it. Question is how do you play audio on hover in each of those images using JS, CSS, or HTML or even Phaser?  It's easy to do if you have just an image map but how about sprites?

Here's an example, https://www.languageguide.org/french/vocabulary/body/

Comment: Could you show us an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Use code as below:

```js
var audio = new Audio("your_autio_location.mp3");

function func() {
  console.log(audio);
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<img src="src.png" class="img" onmouseover="func()" width="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const audio = new Audio("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
const img = document.querySelector('#imageAudio')

img.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  console.log(audio);
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img" id="imageAudio" width="100"/>
```